# Need to stop timer, because it is looping and opening the same window over and over

Tags: c#

I have this screen that is on startup, basically like a splash, but it isn't. I put a timer on it. After a few seconds the window must disappear and then the log in must show. I've got as far as showing the new form, but it is on a loop. It keeps opening the new form again and again! Here is my code. Where am I doing this wrong?

**Timer**

```
int count;
count = 0;

public Windowsplash()
{
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,2500);
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = sender as System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer;

    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    MainWindow _new = new MainWindow();
    _new.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

I want to stop the timer, so that the new window can stop opening the whole time!
Thanks!

PS: I edited it to what I now have

Comment: Why use a counter instead of an interval of 2500?

Comment: _@Kendall how would i use the inerval? and what is the use of it.
  yeah , im new to timers and how they work_

Comment: Just specify an interval of 2500 instead of 500 in the TimeSpan, and then remove the count variable entirely.

Comment: _@KendallFrey can i get some coding because dispatcherTimer.Interval = 2500 isnt working?_

Comment: Just replace 500 with 2500, and keep the TimeSpan.

Comment: Code in Question looks better now ;-)

Comment: hey guys, sorry for late post. @kendall, it worked awsme! the count system sucks!  thnx for all who commented :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int count; 
count = 0; 

public Windowsplash 

    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,500); 
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick); 
    dispatcherTimer.Start(); 

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = sender as System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer; 

        dispatcherTimer.Stop(); 
        MainWindow _new = new MainWindow(); 
        _new.Show(); 
        this.Close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new DispatcherTimer instance in the _Tick handler. And you stop that instance. The old original instance will keep running.

Remove this line from the handler;

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
```

Comment: And more specifically, as he only increments count when its less than five, it means that once it reaches five it will remain there and keep opening new windows.

Comment: _@IvoTops if i remove that line from handler, the name of handler doesnt pick up the name of the dispatchtimer._

Comment: @user1539943 Use the `sender` parameter, as in my answer.

Comment: _@Miika, how would you go bu this to get the count to zero after it has hit 5 counts?_

Answer (score 1):

To improve on IvoTops answer, it looks like you may be creating the timer local to the constructor, so it won't be accessible in the tick handler. Change the first line of your tick event handler to this:

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer
    = sender as System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer;
```

This way you get the original timer that was fired, instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a new `DispatcherTimer` each time in the loop, reuse `sender`, the original `DispatcherTimer`.  Your problem is that the old timers continue to run without any further interaction.